# Laravel 5.4 Forgot Password/Notify Error / Postfix

Tags: laravel, email, configuration, postfix-mta, forgot-password

I’m having some trouble sending my forgot password Email with laravel 5.4 from my production environment.  Mail trap worked fine in development, however in production I am using postfix.  I can send emails manually OK from the production server, but have yet to send them with laravel.

I have included my .env info, the error being received, and my user model

if anyone knows of a solution to this, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=127.0.1.1
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=admin
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null


BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notify() in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2443
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1239): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->__call('notify', Array)
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1332): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('notify', Array)
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/CanResetPassword.php(27): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call('notify', Array)
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php(70): App\User->sendPasswordResetNotification('843ef7a81b8452d...')
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/SendsPasswordResetEmails.php(34): Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker->sendResetLink(Array)
/var/www/laravel/app/Http/Controllers/guestController.php(28): App\Http\Controllers\guestController->sendResetLinkEmail(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
[internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\guestController->sendPasswordEmail(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('sendPasswordEma...', Array)
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(203): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\guestController), 'sendPasswordEma...')
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(160): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(559): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
/var/www/laravel/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php(36): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))



namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
```

Comment: where is your `.env` file used for production.

Comment: .env related variables was at the top of the post